# Converting PDF files to XML files (Powershell)

Tags: xml, powershell, pdf, data-conversion, file-conversion

First, let me introduce that I'm not a coder nor a programmer, hence the reason why I'm seeking for help here. I've tried looking for topics in Stackoverflow regarding Powershell, XML and PDF files. I found many topics for converting XML files to PDF, but (correct me if I'm wrong) none for the other way around (I'm restricting my tools to merely Powershell). What I want to do is to simply use Powershell to convert a PDF file to an XML file.

A lil bit of Googling leads me to a webpage with the following long code. Again, I don't have much knowledge with scripts, so I don't understand 95% of this long code. So, here are my questions:

1. The webpage mentions: 'Demonstrates how to insert any file into XML using base64 encoding, and then extract back to the original file. This example embeds a PDF in the XML, but the type of file does not matter. It can be any type of file.' I wonder why did they say "insert" instead of "convert". What does this code actually do? Will it perform my intended task of "converting a PDF file to XML"?
2. Am I going down a wrong rabbit hole with this code? If this is the right track for my purpose, can someone help explain this code for me? Otherwise, can someone point out if my purpose can actually be sought through Powershell? If so, what are the right scripts/code for that?

Thank you!

> Add-Type -Path
> "C:\chilkat\ChilkatDotNet47-9.5.0-x64\ChilkatDotNet47.dll"
>
> ## Load our PDF file. $bd = New-Object Chilkat.BinData $success = $bd.LoadFile("qa_data/helloWorld.pdf") if ($success -ne $true) {
>
> ```
> $("Failed to load PDF file.")
> exit }
> ```
>
> ## Load the following XML:
>
> ## A base64 encoded PDF file will be inserted under this node.
>
> $xml = New-Object Chilkat.Xml $success =
> $xml.LoadXmlFile("qa_data/xml/xmlToContainPdf.xml") if ($success -ne
> $true) {
> $("Failed to load XML file.")
> exit }
>
> ## Insert the PDF into the XML. $xml.NewChild2("xyz|pdfData",$bd.GetEncoded("base64"))
>
> ## Show the new XML: $($xml.GetXml())
>
> ## The XML now looks like this:
>
> ## A base64 encoded PDF file will be inserted under this node.
>
> ## JVBERi0xL ... UlRU9GCg==
>
> ## To extract the PDF data out and restore the PDF file: $bd2 = New-Object Chilkat.BinData $success =
>
> $bd2.AppendEncoded($xml.GetChildContent("xyz|pdfData"),"base64")
> $success = $bd2.WriteFile("qa_output/helloWorld.pdf")
>
> $("Success.")

Comment: The code inserts the PDF contents into an XML document, it doesn't convert PDF to XML.  Think of it this way, the XML can contain many PDF documents, the code is just inserting one in your example.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: "convert a PDF file to an XML file." Why is converting PDF to XML important for you? What do you do with the XML once you have it?

Answer (score 2):

PDF allows for many ways of representing documents that end up looking exactly the same on paper.

At one extreme, it might just contain the text as an image.

At the other extreme, it might contain all the text in the right order, with just occasional print directives to say where to display the next paragraph.

In between these extremes, it might contain chunks of text in the wrong order, with only the positioning information to tell you how to stitch things back together.

So reading PDF is very similar to optical character recognition, and in fact turning the PDF into an image and then using OCR on the image is often the best way of making progress.

There are software products available that attempt to read PDF, and I suggest you use one of them, rather than trying to do it yourself - especially as you say you're not a programmer.